# How to fix modelformset error: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

Tags: django, django-forms, formset

This is my first attempt at using formsets and I am stuck with this error.  Where am I going wrong? I don't fully understand how this works yet. I think my form is expecting a user but I don't know what to do with it. Thanks for any help!

**error:**

**init**() missing 1 required positional argument: 'user'

**model:**

```
class PropertySubmission(models.Model):

BANNER_CHOICES = (
    ('NB', 'No Banner'),
    ('FL', 'For Lease'),
    ('FS', 'For Sale'),
    ('NL', 'New Listing'),
    ('SD', 'Sold'),
    ('LD', 'Leased'),
    ('RD', 'Reduced'),
    ('NP', 'New Price'),
    ('SC', 'Sold Conditionally'),
    ('CB', 'Custom Banner'),
)

image = models.ImageField(upload_to=user_directory_path, blank=True)
mls_number = models.CharField(max_length=8, blank=True)
headline = models.CharField(max_length=30)
details = RichTextField()
banner = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=BANNER_CHOICES)
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
date_modified = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
program_code = models.ManyToManyField(Program)
product = models.ForeignKey('Product', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
production_cycle = models.ManyToManyField('ProductionCycle')
shell = models.ForeignKey('Shell', on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True)
card_delivery_instructions = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
card_delivery_instructions_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=card_delivery_instructions_image_path, blank=True)
```

**form:**

```
class PropertyCreateKeepInTouchForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = PropertySubmission
    fields = ['headline','details','banner','image','mls_number','program_code']
    help_texts = {
        'details': '110 characters maximum',

    }

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super().clean()
    image = cleaned_data.get("image")
    mls_number = cleaned_data.get("mls_number")
    program_code = cleaned_data.get("program_code")

    if mls_number == '' and image is None:
        # Only do something if one field are valid so far.
        self.add_error('image', 'Please provide an image or MLS number')
        self.add_error('mls_number', 'Please provide an image or MLS number')
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please provide a number")

    if program_code is None:
        self.add_error('program_code', 'Please select one or more programs')
        raise forms.ValidationError("Please select one or more program")

def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
    super(PropertyCreateKeepInTouchForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    #self.fields['details'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={'rows':4, 'cols':15, 'maxlength':110})
    self.fields['details'].label = "Provide Feature Property Details:"
    self.fields['program_code'].widget = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple()
    self.fields['program_code'].queryset = Program.objects.filter(client=user).filter(production_cycles__product_name__name='Keep In Touch').filter(production_cycles__submission_deadline__lt=timezone.now()+timedelta(days=30)).filter(production_cycles__submission_deadline__gt=timezone.now()).distinct()
    self.fields['program_code'].label = "Select Programs"
    self.fields['mls_number'].label = "number - to retrieve a photo of the property."
    self.fields['image'].label = "Property Photo"
    self.fields['banner'].label = "Select a banner"
    self.fields['headline'].label = "Provide a headline"
```

**view:**

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
@login_required
def create_properties_keepintouch(request, num_forms):

property_formset = modelformset_factory(PropertySubmission, form=PropertyCreateKeepInTouchForm, extra=1)

formset = property_formset(queryset=PropertySubmission.objects.none())

return render(request, 'programs/property_submission_create_formset.html', {'formset': formset, 'num_forms':num_forms})
```

**template:**

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ formset.management_form }}
{% for form in formset %}
<div class="row form-row spacer">


    <div class="col-6">
        <hr>
        <div class="input-group">

            {{ form.media }}
            {{form.as_p}}


        </div>
    </div>
</div>
{% endfor %}
<div class="row spacer">
    <div class="col-4 offset-2">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-primary">Create</button>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd want to use [`form_kwargs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/forms/formsets/#passing-custom-parameters-to-formset-forms):

```
formset = property_formset(
    queryset=PropertySubmission.objects.none(), 
    form_kwargs={'user': request.user}
)
```

Comment: This worked! I really should have thoroughly read the docs. Just a small correction: form_kwargs={'user': request.user} not )

Answer (score 0):

You have overloaded `PropertyCreateKeepInTouchForm __init__` method as you need to pass a user. However as far as I understand, `modelform_factory` and `modelformset_factory` functions don't allow passing arbitrary arguments.

So to the best of my knowledge, you will need to create your formset manually, not with a factory function.

Comment: Or you can use [partial](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58616753/10746224)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to accomplish this is to use [`functools.partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/functools.html#functools.partial):

```
from functools import partial

def create_properties_keepintouch(request, num_forms):

    form = partial(PropertyCreateKeepInTouchForm, request.user)
    property_formset = modelformset_factory(PropertySubmission, form=form, extra=1)
    ...
```

Basically, this passes the `user` argument to the `__init__` function before you actually call it, which allows Django to initialize the form class itself.